# Magento 2 - Make fields in custom form required

Tags: magento2, model, phtml, form-validation, required

I created a custom controller and model where users can save bank payment data information.

I added a form where users can change data from the model.

[image]

Is there a way to reuse the magento code to implement form validation, or do I have to create a custom solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/validations/custom-form-validation.html).